# dataContractSerializer known types

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have stumbled upon the following declaration in dataContractSerializer known types for a WCF service  :

```
<dataContractSerializer>
<declaredTypes>
     <add type="Common.Rules.Rule`1, Common.Rules">
     ...
     </add>
</declaredTypes>
</dataContractSerializer>
```

is the "`1"  some sort of regex , or is there some other use for that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It specifies number of type parameters:

> Backtick (`) - 
>   Precedes one or more digits representing the number of type parameters, located at the end of the name of a generic type.[<sup>Source</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)